# how to apply multiple addition in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

Hi Have below data from below query ..
(index=abc OR index=def) |rex field=index "(?<Local_Market>[^cita]\w.*?)_" | chart count by blocked , Local_Market

blocked     dub rat mil
0       10  20  21
1       02  03  09
2       9   2   1

Now i want the data as below

total bolocked(sumof 0 and sumof 2)   dub   rat     mil     total found(Sumof 1)
(10+20+21+9+2+1)=63               10    20       21     (02+03+09)=14

Comment: Unless your `index` names start with that regex, you're not going to get any data out

Answer (score 1):

The question could be better formatted, but I think what you want is the `addcoltotals` command.

Comment: Hi Rich,in addcoltotals  we will get total of all blocked one ..but i want only blocked(0&2) together and blocked 1 together

Comment: Hi @RichG,in addcoltotals  we will get total of all blocked one ..but i want only blocked(0&2) together and blocked 1 together

Comment: Please reformat the data in the question into a table form so it's easier to understand the relationships.  Then please explain how Splunk is to know which fields to add together.

Comment: blocked   dub rat mil
0          10 20 21
1          2 3 9
2         9 2 1
         
total bolocked(sumof 0 and sumof 2) dub rat mil total found(Sumof 1)
(10+20+21+9+2+1)=63                         10 20 21 (02+03+09)=14
         
total bolocked(sumof 0 and sumof 2) dub rat mil total found(Sumof 1)
63                                                          10 20 21 14

Comment: (index=abc OR index=def) |rex field=index "(?<Local_Market>[^cita]\w.*?)_" | chart count by blocked , Local_Market
blocked   dub rat mil
0          10 20 21
1          2 3 9
2         9 2 1                                                                                               i want the data as below          
total bolocked(sumof 0 and sumof 2) dub rat mil total found(Sumof 1)
(10+20+21+9+2+1)=63                         10 20 21 (02+03+09)=14
in short i want data in below format          
total bolocked   dub rat mil total found(Sumof 1)
63                          10 20 21 14

Answer (score 0):

This run-anywhere example is ugly, but I believe it produces the desired results.

````
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="blocked dub rat mil
0       10  20  21
1       02  03  09
2       9   2   1"
| multikv forceheader=1
| fields - _time _raw linecount
```Skip the above - it just creates test data```
```Compute the total_bolocked field for blocked=0 and blocked=2```
| eval total_bolocked=if(blocked!=1,dub+mil+rat,0)
```Compute the total_found field for blocked=1```
| eval total_found=if(blocked=1, dub+mil+rat,0)
```Add up the total_bolocked fields.  This will include blocked=1, but we'll fix that below```
| eventstats sum(total_bolocked) as total_bolocked
```Set total_bolocked=0 if blocked is 1```
| eval total_bolocked=if(blocked=1,0, total_bolocked)
````